# DROP database doesn't appear to drop all database objects

Tags: postgresql

I am kind of new to Postgres and am using recent version on Mac.  I'm writing a `.sql` script that will create a database and tables and load data.  (I need to be able to automate this, so I will be running it in a `cron` job, I will NOT be running it from within `psql` shell.)  Every time I run, I want to start from a clean slate, wiping out the database and all its objects.

When I run the below commands from bash in a `.sql` file with this content:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydb;
CREATE DATABASE mydb;
CREATE TABLE progress (
foo character varying(10)
);
```

Then

```
psql -U postgres -d some_db -a -f db_etl.sql
```

results in:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydb;
DROP DATABASE
CREATE DATABASE mydb;
CREATE DATABASE
CREATE TABLE progress (
    foo character varying(10)
);
psql:db_etl.sql:17: ERROR:  relation "progress" already exists
```

How could the relation still exist if the `DROP` of its database was successful?  Do I need to be using fully qualified object names like `my_db.public.progress`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could the relation still exist if the DROP of its database was successful? Do I need to be using fully qualified object names like my_db.public.progress?

You can't `DROP` the database you're connected to.

```
psql -U postgres -d some_db -a -f db_etl.sql
```

That shows you're connecting to `some_db`, then you're trying to recreate the database `mydb` and then you're trying to create the table `progress` on `some_db`.

If you want to create the table `progress` on the newly created `mydb` you'll have to use `psql -d mydb` or `\connect` to it explicitly in psql after you create it.

Comment: solution is to add \c mydb after the creation of that db.

Answer (score 3):

You can't drop the database you are currently connected to.  You are connected to `some_db`, not `mydb`.  You drop `mydb`, then create `mydb` agsin, but you don't change your connection from `some_db` to `mydb`. Creating a database does not automatically change your connection to the newly created database.  So the table you created is attempted to be created in `some_db`, where it evidently already exists.

You can't create objects in a database you are not connected to, so fully qualifying the object name will not help.  You can use the `psql` meta-command `\c` to change your connected database in the `.sql` script.  Of course you have to go through authentication again.